# Microsoft sync framework - Alternative to triggers

Tags: .net, sql-server, synchronization

I am thinking to use Microsoft sync framework, but one of the problems is that the database(Sql Server 2005) has the triggers disabled and there is a process that disable triggers if there is one. So I can not use triggers. And I CAN NOT put extra code on the application which is inserting, deleting and updating the table.

So the problem is that MSF create triggers(when it is provisioning) for tracking transaction. but in my case those triggers are going to be useless.

Could anybody tell me if there is any way to use Microsoft Sync Framework without triggers? or anyway to replace them with something similar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: After someone has shot themselves in the foot with a revolver, I'm not sure the best thing to do is to hand them a rock and send them back into the fight.   Enable triggers and stop shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I would enable triggers, the problem is the other team they say no, they said if you resolve it it without triggers we will accept it.

Comment: The obvious alternative is to upgrade the database to 2008 so you can make use of change tracking instead. If they're not happy with that solution, it sound more like a people issue than a technology one.

Comment: It has to support 2005, so it's not an option, thanks though.

Comment: It is NOT duplicated